# How do I remove my dynamically added textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

here in my codebehind I have created a way to add `asp:Textbox` dynamically

Create button action to create text field

```
List<string> controlIdList = new List<string>();
int counter = 0;
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    controlIdList = (List<string>)ViewState["controlIdList"];
    foreach (string Id in controlIdList)
    {
        counter++;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = Id;
        LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
        LiteralControl openLI = new LiteralControl("<li>");
        LiteralControl closeLI = new LiteralControl("</li>");

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(openLI);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(closeLI);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(linebreak);
    }
}


protected void btnAddTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {               

        counter++;
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "Textbox" + counter;

        LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(linebreak);
        controlIdList.Add(tb.ID);
        ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to remove the button all that happens is a postback. The control does not get removed. Here is what I have tried:

**Edited**
This works now but for some reason the textbox does not delete the first time I click the button on the second click the textbox gets removed

```
protected void btnRemoveTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {
        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "Textbox" + counter;
        if ((control.ID == tb.ID.ToString()) && (control.ID != null))
        {
            controlIdList.Remove(tb.ID);
            ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure counter has the correct value? Are you sure postback isn't recreating the control at some point? Set breakpoints in your code and step through it so you can see what's happening and in what order.

Comment: The method for creating and deleting textboxes are name the same (copy and paste error?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have your data wrapped in an *Update Panel*, otherwise every time your page has to go to the server a *Postback* will occur.  That way when your logic hits the server, your remove logic can indeed execute without the *Postback*.

You could also simply set the control visibility to false.

Another possibility would be to do a large chunk of this via the Client, which would be as simple as `.hide();` or `.show();` with jQuery.

Also keep in mind your approach will create difficulties in maintaining the *View State*.  Another issue with the proposed solution, an *Update Panel* stores the page in memory then recreates it via Ajax.

`<asp:UpdatePanel>` would be what you need to avoid a *Postback*.

Honestly you could do it quite simply like:

```
... btnRemoveTextbox_Click(..., ...)
{
     txtDynamic.Visibility = false;
}
```

As I said, though you can do this with the server you may be better off with *Client Side* then call, a *Service*.

**Important:** If those are your *Event Handler* names, you shouldn't have both be identical when you have two separate task designed for them.

---

**Update/Example**

```
// Front-End:
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scmPage" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updDemo" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhControl" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCreateText" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="btnCreateText_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnRemoveText" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="btnRemoveText_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

// Backend:
protected void btnCreateText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = new TextBox();
    text.ID = "txtDynamic";

    plhControl.Controls.Add(text);

}

protected void btnRemoveText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = new TextBox();
    text.ID = "txtDynamic";
    text.Visible = false;
}
```

And that actually works, I just tried it.  One thing to note here, you need to ensure you have a valid id and populate the proper control.

**This code is incredibly rough, it wouldn't be wise for production because it works for a control that has that single Id or contain validation.  You would need to loop through the controls, ensure the proper Id is detected and exist before attempting to remove.  You'll need to debug your code and validate.**

Comment: I made the error when I copy and pasted the code to Stack Overflow. This error does not exist in my code

Comment: If I try your simple solution how would I go about calling the dynamic textfield? I tried using this but it still only makes a postback

foreach (Control myControl in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
            {               
                if (myControl.ID == counter.ToString)
                {
                    myControl.Visible = false;
                }
            }

Comment: @ObadiahWilliams You need to wrap your form page in an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` on the front-end.

Comment: your suggestion works for deleting the button, but for some reason, I have to click the button twice to remove it. I updated my remove code to show my changes

Comment: Greg I updated my remove(control) code based on your suggestion. although it does not remove the textfield on first click I agree with your suggestion. Did I execute it properly?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove textbox from your placeholder like below:

```
protected void Remove(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {
        //Here you need to take ID from ViewState["controlIdList"]
        if (control.ID == "TakeIDFromControlListsID")
        {
            Controls.Remove(control);
            control.Dispose();
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This has been tried...please look at my solution posted in the original question. It does not work, the page simply posts back

Comment: Look My code edited or  Try This :this.Controls.Clear();

Comment: please specify what you mean by "TakeIDFromControlListsID" is would this be counter.ToString()?

Comment: take ID from ViewState["controlIdList"]

Comment: here "Textbox" + counter you have your ID ?