# Why does my dynamic textbox not remove on first click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I started [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965942/how-do-i-remove-my-dynamically-added-textbox) and was able to get an answer to my original question. Now the textbox gets removed but only the second time I click the remove button. Here is what I have tried

```
protected void btnRemoveTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
    {
        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "Textbox" + counter;
        if ((control.ID == tb.ID.ToString()) && (control.ID != null))
        {
            controlIdList.Remove(tb.ID);
            ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;
        }
    }
}
```

When I step through using breakpoints and error debugging the code runs through twice without error however on the second time through it removes the button.

Comment: What does your Page_Load method look like? And do you have a Page_PreRender method?

Comment: Because you created and added textboxes in `LoadViewState` method (earlier in the the page's life cycle), and here only remove an id from `controlIdList` but not from the control tree. Note: you do not need  to create a new `TextBox` instance in `btnRemoveTextBox_Click` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you created and added textboxes in `LoadViewState` method (earlier in the the page's life cycle), and here only remove an id from `controlIdList` but not from the control tree. Note: you do not need to create new `TextBox` instances in `btnRemoveTextBox_Click` method.

```
protected void btnRemoveTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
  {
    string id = "Textbox" + counter;
    if (control.ID == id)
    {
      controlIdList.Remove(id);
      PlaceHolder1.Controls.Remove(control);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```