# How do I retrieve data from my dynamic textboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have some dynamic `asp:TextBox` added to my application: See my [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965942/how-do-i-remove-my-dynamically-added-textbox)

```
protected void AddBoxes()
{
    counter++;
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "Textbox" + counter;
    tb.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
    tb.Rows = 5;
    tb.CssClass = "larger_tb";
    LiteralControl linebreak = new LiteralControl("<br />");
    LiteralControl openLI = new LiteralControl("<li>");
    LiteralControl closeLI = new LiteralControl("</li>");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(openLI);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tb);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(closeLI);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(linebreak);
    controlIdList.Add(tb.ID);
    ViewState["controlIdList"] = controlIdList;
}
```

Now I want to extract the info from these directly to a label. I know I will need to use a loop because I will not know how many the user selected. This is what I have tried:

```
foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        lblScope.Text = "<li>" + PlaceHolder1.Controls[i].ToString() +"</li>";
    }
}
```

However all this does is print out `System.Web.UI.LiteralControl`. How should this be done?

**Edited**
[image]
This is what is happening when I try:

```
foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)control;
        lblScope.Text += string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", txt.Text);
    }
}
```

How do I stop the code from printing the name of the first textbox the user created?

Comment: you need to cast it.

Comment: @DanielA.White please explain

Comment: `PlaceHolder1.Controls[...]` returns a control. you need to cast it to a `LiteralControl` to get the `Text` property.

Comment: @ObadiahWilliams you don't want to see "YEAH!"?

Comment: I don't want it to print out "Textbox 4"

Comment: @ObadiahWilliams So, the FIRST not LAST!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lblScope.Text = "";

foreach (Control control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)control;
        lblScope.Text += string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", txt.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: this loops through my info but  first it gives the name of the last textbox for example. .Textbox4, oranges, apples, bananas, pears. how do I stop it from printing the last textbox name?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I updated my question to show you what was happening.

Comment: the update removes all the itterations and simply prints the name of the last textbox the user created "Textbox 4". Your previous code worked it was itterating all the text from the dynamic text fields. I am just trying to figure out why it is printing out the last textbox name

Comment: @ObadiahWilliams just assign an empty string to `lblScope.Text` before the loop and use the previous code.

Comment: I added the 'i=0' before the if statement and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ProcessAllControls(Control rootControl)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in rootControl.Controls)
    {
         if(childControl is TextBox)
         {  
              TextBox txt = (TextBox)childControl;             
              lblScope.Text += string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", txt.Text);
         }
         else
         {     
              ProcessAllControls(childControl);
         }   
    }
}
```

You need to use recursion if you have nested Checkboxes in other controls in your rootControl.You will call the method like this:

```
ProcessAllControls(PlaceHolder1);
```

What we are doing: We loop all the controls in PlaceHolder1, if the control is  checkbox we are adding text to the label in the PlaceHolder1. If not calling the same method to check if there is nested checkboxes in the current control. This is executed for all the controls. Like I said this is called recursion.

Comment: Error 178 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found

Comment: I edited to become more clear. Be sure that you copy pasted it correctly. There is no way this code to run on UI.Control because you are making check if childControl is TextBox.